# How to disable EmEditor from context menu?

Tags: emeditor

Exaclty as the title. I don't want EmEditor show up when I right click an .exe (it only says EmEditor), or
a folder (Find in Files with EmEditor), or an png file (only EmEditor), or anything else.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clear the **Add a shortcut to the Context Menu on Explorer** check box in the **Shortcut** page of the **Customize** dialog box.

Comment: Thanks. But I couldn't find it and thought it might be on install wizard. And It was there.

I can't upvote cause I'm a new member.

Comment: It is also included in the Installer. During install, select `CUSTOM` install, and then you can clear the `Context Menu`. Instead of upvoting, please click the green check mark by my answer.